# Server socket not sending data to client after recieving data

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am working on a simple socket program which is supposed to measure the time it takes to transfer data over the network using various sizes of packets. The program runs fine until I want the server to respond to the client, telling the client that all data has been recieved. Below you will find the code:

Server:

```
def server():
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind(('127.0.0.1',6000))
    s.listen(1)
    con,addr=s.accept()
    while 1:
        data = con.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
    print "Test"
    con.send("Done")
    con.close()
```

Client:

```
def client():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1',6000))
    data = ""
    for j in range(0,1024):
        data = data + "a"
    start = int(time.time()*1000.0)
    for i in range(0,15):
        s.send(data)
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if data=="Done":
        end = int(time.time()*1000.0)
        s.close()
        print str(end-start)+"ms"
```

As I said, the program runs fine until I try to respond from the server to the client. When the program comes to `con.send("Done")` in the server and `s.recv(1024)` in the cliet it stops, also the text "Test" is never printed in the server. If I remove `con.send("Done")` and `s.recv(1024)` in the client everything runs fine, and it runs fine if I remove the code to send the data from the client to the server as well, thus only sending data from the server.

I have been looking at examples, and I can't find any faulty code. So my question is why this doesn't work? And, also, do I even need the server to tell the client that it's done, or is there a more efficient way for the client to know when the server has recieved all the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need nonblocking IO or threads. Otherwise read operations may block your program and thus prevent writes from making progress, or vice versa.

Comment: it just happens to work because write buffers are large enough to hold your written data, send it to the remote client, the remove client reads it and then sends a response which in turn allows the following read to unblock. don't rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is threading or non-blocking connections. I just wrote [a non-blocking TCP server that just runs out of the box](http://github.com/gragas/simpletcp). Here's an echo server:

```
from simpletcp.tcpserver import TCPServer

def echo(ip, queue, data):
    queue.put(data)

server = TCPServer("localhost", 5000, echo)
server.run()
```

And here's what a client would look like:

```
from simpletcp.clientsocket import ClientSocket

s1 = ClientSocket("localhost", 5000, single_use=False)
response = s1.send("Hello, World!")
```

If you don't want to use that, there's always the built-in [SocketServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html).

Either way, there's no point in writing code that someone else has already written for you.